# Doesn’t “a” need to mean “one”?

Tags: indefinite-article

Can I say  “I ate a hamburger” when I ate half of a hamburger?

We say “we drink water” even when we drink some of water.

Is it obligatory that “I ate a hamburger” means “I ate one hamburger”?

Comment: What is it about eating half hamburgers?  Do you **really** do this.

Comment: @James K That’s fine because I say “eating half hamburgers” when I’m speaking, but when I’m hearing, I should know what it means, so I’m afraid that I misunderstand.

Comment: Your sentence is correct, but your question is not really about articles. You should be looking for an idiomatic way of expressing your idea. And there is no fixed way of saying it. I would choose something like, "I hate part of a hamburger." Someone else might say, "I ate half of a hamburger." Another person might think the distinction is irrelevant and say, "I ate a hamburger."

Comment: I also hate part of a hamburger, @JeffreyCarney

Comment: @Paribus Ceteris Facepalm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes "a hamburger" means one hamburger.

Now with some objects, for example clouds, if they are cut in half, you get two smaller objects of the same type.  "Steak" might be like this.

> My wife bought a large steak. She cut it in half and shared it with me, so we both ate a small steak.

And some things are not like that.

> Solomon suggested that the baby should be cut in half, and each woman should take half the baby.

Generally simple things that don't have components are like clouds.  Complex things are like babies

Hamburgers could be thought of as being more like a cloud, or more like a baby.  For many people if you cut a hamburger in half, it isn't really the same as a small burger, but that is a matter of expression. If you want to give that meaning you can.

It is pretty rare that it matters. You also need to be aware of what you want to communicate: Why are telling the person what you ate?  Why does that person need to know the amount?

> Please can I get an ice cream!? I'm really hungry. I only had *half* a hamburger for lunch!

> Well I had a hamburger for lunch so I want something healthy for dinner.

In the first case "half" is important. In the second it isn't. This is what Jeff Carney is saying in his comment: 'Someone else might say, "I ate half of a hamburger." Another person might think the distinction is irrelevant and say, "I ate a hamburger."'

The comparison with "water" is not good, because water is non-countable in that context.

Comment: When is water by itself (without, for example, "bottle of" prefixed) countable?

Comment: Never, that I can think of. Water is a substance, not an object.

Comment: You can say "I'll have a water" to mean "a glass of water" by synodoche